# Completion of n-fold Segal spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

During a reading course about Jacob Lurie's paper about [Local TQFTs](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/cobordism.pdf), I came across the notion of Segal spaces as models for $(\infty,1)$-categories. Looking at things like the "double nerve" for 2-categories, I also understand why $n$-fold Segal spaces provide a model for $(\infty, n)$-categories. What puzzles me is the completion of $n$-fold Segal spaces. There is a construction for $n=1$ in the case of bisimplicial sets by Rezk in his paper about [the homotopy theory of homotopy theory](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Rezk&s5=Homotopy%20theory&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=1804411). I can imagine that something similar can be done for Segal spaces which are simplicial *spaces* instead of *bisimplicial sets*. My questions are:

> How does the completion generalize to $n$-fold Segal spaces?

and

> Is the completion a fibrant replacement in the model category structure on simplicial spaces?